# Can you add a UIButton be used as the UI for a SKSpriteNode?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, uikit, uibutton, skspritenode

I have `UIButton` that I created with custom UI properties and I want to add animations to it where it has a gravity and falls downwards using SpriteKit. Is it possible to `SKSpriteNode` support my UIButton as its / is it possible to combine SKSpriteNodes and UIViews at all?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Searching for your question: `Can you add a UIButton be used as the UI for a SKSpriteNode?` on Google returns many relevant results...

Comment: no, UIKit gui elements don't work inside SpriteKit. (the lack of a gui library for SpriteKit is one of the worst things about it imo.) what you *can* do is overlay gui elements from UIKit or SwiftUI in a clear layer over the top. this works for things like heads-up-display. but won't help you if you want gravity effects etc

Answer (score 0):

For using the UIKit in SpriteKit use these functions using the view of a SKScene:

```swift
import SpriteKit
import UIKit

class Scene: SKScene {
    var button: UIButton = UIButton()

    //Adds the button to the view.
    func addButton() {
        if self.view != nil {
            self.view?.addSubView(button)
        }
    }
    ///IMPORTANT function when moving from view to other view for example.
    func removeButton() {
        if self.view != nil {
            //Removes the button from its super.view
            self.button.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```

The second function is very important, because if you don’t use it when changing the scene, the subviews you added will not delete.

For more information, visit https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622616-addsubview#managing-the-view-hierarchy

Btw, UIKit and SpriteKit use different coordinates methods, be careful.